# Are Mantras really Locked?

Tags: scripture, vedas, mantras

In the Internet we see many sites which claim that Mantras are locked in Kaliyuga. Are the mantras really locked? Why are they locked? 
 
Also does anyone know methods to unlock Mantras which can be propagated in public if they are locked?

Comment: Who said all Mantras are locked other than Hare Krishna Mantra?

Comment: `other than Hare Krishna` is my inference after going through scripture where Nārada was told about significance of Hare Krishna mantra. So I think it is not locked.

Comment: It's not correct. Kali Sanatarana Upanishad is believed to be composed during 16th century. It is the source of Hare Krishna mantra. No. If this was really true, why would Priests be performing many Yajnas across India and why would many temples use Veda and Agama mantras? Everywhere it should be Hare Krishna Mantra.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Hare Krishna mantra doesn't give powers, only for devotion. To not get distracted. Moreover, I'm saying based on the scripture it might not. If even `Hare Krishna` mantra is not working or it's not a mantra, no mantra is working.

Comment: And where did you get this information that all mantras are 'locked'?? What is your source for this erroneous information? Another my auntie told me so question.

Comment: @RohitSinghRathore Add reference for the locking of Mantras statement. Also, we can't say a Mantra is not working if we are not able to feel sometime.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda ji. See, Mantras are locked. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all a siddha mantra means one that is unlocked.

There is no mantra that is permanently locked for some particular Yuga. Even if the Devi Bhagavata Purana says that Gayatri is cursed to be ineffective, then there are the shapa vimochana mantras as well.

So does that mean Gayatri is really locked? You can start chanting it by taking the mantra from a Guru and it will work.

However, each mantra is initially locked. The Tantrik mantras, for example has the 6 limbs viz : Rishi , Devata, Chandah, Bija, Shakti and Kilaka. Of which the kilaka literally means the lock.

So, without knowing the kilaka, japa does not bear fruit. All these angas are in fact kind of a lock each. We unlock the mantra by planting them on various places (like rishi nyasa is done on the top of head, Devata nyasa in the heart etc) with appropriate mantras and mudras during japa. Only then japa gives the full results.

But mantras can have as many as 60 doshas or defects and before chanting  hence it is needed to purify them with the dasasamskaras. In KulArnava Tantram the 60 mantra doshas and 10 samskaras are mentioned by Lord Shiva as follows:

> Rudhah KutAksharo Mugdho Vaddhah Kruddhascha Bheditah | VAlah KumAro
>   Yuvakaha Proura Bhriddhascha Garvitaha || ...... Nirviryo Bhramito
>   Supta rinaklishtahangahinakah |....... ShashtyatAn MantrdoshAmscha
>   YohagyAtvA Prajapenmanum | Siddhirna JAyate Tasya LakshyakotijapAdapi
>   ||
>
> ..............
>
> Ruddha (blocked), Kutakshara, Mugdha, Baddha (bound), Kruddha (angry),
>   Bhedita (pierced), Valaka (boy), kumara, Yuvaka, , Proura ( old),
>   BHriddha, Garvita (proud), Stambhita, Murchita ( unconscious),
>   ...Achetan (lacking consciousness), ...Nirjiva (lifeless), Ari
>   (enemy), ....Tiraskrita (condemned), ....Abhisapagrasta (cursed),
>   Angahina (lacking the limbs), jada ( dead)... Thes rae the sixty
>   mantra doshas. If mantra japa is done without knowing these doshas
>   then even one lakh crores of japa can't give siddhi or fruits.
>
> **KulArnava Tantram, Chapter 15, verses 66- 71.**

.........................

> Kathyante Dasa SamskArA MantradoshaharAh Priye | Jananam Jivanam
>   PaschAttAranam Vodhanam Tatah || Abhisekahatha VimalikarnopyAyane
>   TathA | Tarpanam Dipanam Guptihi SamskArAha KulanAyike ||
>
> ............
>
> Priye, I am saying the dasa samskaras that removes the errors (doshas)
>   of mantras. Hey Kulanayike, Janana, Jeevana, TArana, Bodhana,
>   Abhisekha, Vimalikarana, ApyAyana, Tarpana, Dipan, and Gupti---- These
>   are the dasa samskaras.
>
> **KUlArnAva Tantram, Chapter 15, Verses 72, 73**

A very brief description of these samskaras are as follows:

> **Janana**
>
> The process of successive recovering of mantras from matrika yantra (
>   i can't explain to you what is matrika yantra within few lines).
>
> **Jivana**
>
> The successive varnas or mantras thus recovered are then to be chanted
>   separately preceded by OM for 100 or 10 times.
>
> **TArana**
>
> All the varnas of the mantra are to be separated. Then each varnas are
>   to be separately chanted for 100 or 10 times. Then the varnas are to
>   be separately written down by adding the vayu beejam or YAM to them
>   and thereafter water mixed with sandal paste is to be sprinkled on
>   them. This is TArna.
>
> **Vimalikarana**
>
> The mantra is to be imagined at the bottom and middle of the sushumna
>   nadi and the malatrayas (the three impurities anvaya, mayik etc) are
>   to be burnt off using the Jyotir mantra (omitted the mantra).
>
> ...

Also, **most importantly**, there are several mantras like the Sruti mantras (Veda mantras) , ekakshara mantras (OM, Hrim, Houm etc) for which siddhadi nirnaya is not needed at all. That is they are permanently unlocked.

Even the Gayatri mantra was just cursed. It was not locked. Being cursed is just one of the doshas given in the above list. And, it can removed by using the curse removal mantras.

> Mantrosiddhopadishteshu ChaturamnAyajeshu Cha | MAlAmantreshu Deveshi
>   SiddhAdinaiva Shodhyeth ||
>
> ..............
>
> Deveshi, Mantra obtained from a siddha Guru is always siddha. **There is
>   no need for sidhAdhi nirnaya for the mantras that are originated from
>   the five Amnayas and for mala mantras.**
>
> **KulArnava Tantram 15. 100.**

**MAlA mantra :**

A mantra that contains more than 20 alphabets or varnas.

**Amnaya :**

In Parasurama Kalpasutra's (1.2) commentary RAmeswara writes:

> The principle meaning of the word Amnaya is Veda but since Tantras are
>   the essence of Vedas it can also mean the Tantras.

There are 5 Amnayas in all which originated from the 5 faces of Lord Shiva.

So,the import of the above verse is that all mantras that are found in Vedas as well as in the Tantras are unlocked. Temporary locks are however there on all Tantrik mantras in form of the kilaka as already discussed.

Also note that  Veda mantras don't have even the kilaka or the temporary lock.

Finally adding the following verse from the Viswa SAra Tantram which says:

> MahAdikshA TathA DikshA Upadesastah Param | Yuge Yuge Cha Kartabya
>   Upadese Kalou Yuge.....||
>
> .........
>
> In the other three yugas performance of Diksha, Manhadiksha and
>   Upadesha are to be done. **In Kali Yuga only Upadesha can bring forth
>   the desired results.**

So, if the mantras are all locked this advice would not have  made any sense. Because what is the use of giving locked mantras after all?

Answer (score 1):

So far as I know there isn't a lock on all Mantras.  But Shaktas do speak of a lock on the Gayatri mantra.  Here is what [this chapter](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/db/bk11ch16.htm) of the Devi  Bhagavatam says:

> Next for the freedom of the curse of Gâyatrî, do the things properly. Brahmâ gave a curse to Gâyatrî; Vis’vâmitra gave a curse to Her and Vas’istha also cursed Her. These are the three curses; they are removed in due order by recollecting Brahmâ, Vis’vâmitra and Vas’istha.

But this should be taken with a grain of salt, since many people believe that the Devi Bhagavatam is neither one of Vyasa's 18 Mahapuranas nor one of Vyasa's 18 Upapuranas.

Comment: You should stop saying "Devi Bhagavatam is neither one of Vyasa's 18 Mahapuranas nor one of Vyasa's 18 Upapuranas.". There are many debates happened over what Bhagavatam is true, either Devi or Krishna's. Shaktas believe Devi Bhagavatam is true while Vaishnava believe Krishna's Bhagavatam is true.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Even many non-Vaishnavas believe the Devi Bhagavatam is a later creation.

Comment: Can you ever answer a question without editorializing it with some sectarian bias??

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda, could I ask the same question of you ? many of your answers or comments are something along the lines of 'In realm of Maya' or 'Sruti only not Smriti' , 'this is superstition, not vedas' etc. Even by your very definition of Maya, it is not possible to be truly objective because the density of Maya surrounding each person could be different. As long as we are speaking to another person, on the internet no less, each person will have his own bias or subjectivity. That is the whole point of debates. If everyone agreed on everything, we could shut down this site today.

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59520/discussion-on-answer-by-keshav-srinivasan-are-mantras-really-locked).